# MS Word VBA copy and paste rows

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm having trouble with my code and I'm not sure why it is not working.  I would like to attach this to a button on MS word that would allow me to copy several rows within a table and paste them at the end.  Attached is my code I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Sub Add_Facility10_Click()
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(1).Range.Copy
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(2).Range.Copy
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(3).Range.Copy
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(4).Range.Copy
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(5).Range.Copy
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(6).Range.Copy
      ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Range.Last.Cells.Paste

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy rows like that. Essentially, you are copying them to your clipboard where you only have access to one at a time. So you will have to paste each one after you copy. Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Facility10_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 6
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Add
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Count).Range.Paste
        ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Last.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: for some reason it's giving me an error stating 'can't find project or library'

Comment: @PeterNguyen sry, little premature there, it should be fine now.

Comment: it works! However for some reason it repeats row 1 twice.  At the beginning of the copied text and at the end.  Is there a way to fix that?